# How to enable PouchDB Debug in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb, node-debugger

I am developing a prototype web application. I used Yeoman to create an Angular application with Grunt, NPM, and Bower etc. The [PouchDB API](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#debug_mode) says you can enable debugging like so:

```
PouchDB.debug.enable('*');
```

This however requires the [node debug module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/debug) to be installed. I have tried installing it via bower and referencing it in my index.html but to no avail. How do I inject the debug module into Angular? Or is this function only available when the PouchDB is ran from a Node.js server?

EDIT:

The exact error I am getting is bellow. The line it complains about is: `PouchDB.debug.enable('*');`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/taskdb.js:13:15)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4140:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3998:24)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3982:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3947:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4088:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120:13)
angular.js:11413 TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/taskdb.js:13:15)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4140:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3998:24)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3982:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4129:17)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3947:37
    at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4088:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120:13) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use PouchDB, the debug module is already installed. You don't need to do anything except call `PouchDB.debug.enable('*')`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I must be doing something wrong then as it still doesn't work. I have updated my question.

Comment: Ah okay, I see now. Debugging is only available in PouchDB 3.2.0+!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in PouchDB v7.0.0 [loading a separate plugin](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#debug_mode) is required for this.